# Kitchen faucet only gets lukewarm, never gets hot

Tags: plumbing, hot-water

Recently my kitchen faucet will only become warm but never hot. Both water valves are completely opened. Every other faucet in the home get hot and work properly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you start by unscrewing your hot line, of course close the valve first. Then open the valve into a large bucket to make sure you have sufficient pressure and flow and hot water. If everything is good then you probably have a block in the line from the valve to the faucet or you have a bad faucet. Sometimes faucets get plugged or the a lever doesn’t open fully. Good luck.